# codeigniter teamspeak 3 api problems when loading libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, teamspeak

I'm trying to develop a teamspeak web application with the codeigniter web framework. Now I had one problem.

I got following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'TeamSpeak3_Helper_Profiler' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teamspeak\application\libraries\ teamspeak\TeamSpeak3.php on line 550
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'TeamSpeak3_Helper_Profiler' not found

Filename: teamspeak/TeamSpeak3.php

Line Number: 550

Backtrace:
```

My libraries folder structure:

```
C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\PROJECT\TEAMSPEAK\APPLICATION\LIBRARIES
│   Bcrypt.php
│   Curl.php
│   index.html
│   Ion_auth.php
│
└───teamspeak
    │   Exception.php
    │   TeamSpeak3.php
    │
    ├───Adapter
    │   │   Abstract.php
    │   │   Blacklist.php
    │   │   Exception.php
    │   │   FileTransfer.php
    │   │   ServerQuery.php
    │   │   TSDNS.php
    │   │   Update.php
    │   │
    │   ├───Blacklist
    │   │       Exception.php
    │   │
    │   ├───FileTransfer
    │   │       Exception.php
    │   │
    │   ├───ServerQuery
    │   │       Event.php
    │   │       Exception.php
    │   │       Reply.php
    │   │
    │   ├───TSDNS
    │   │       Exception.php
    │   │
    │   └───Update
    │           Exception.php
    │
    ├───Helper
    │   │   Char.php
    │   │   Convert.php
    │   │   Crypt.php
    │   │   Exception.php
    │   │   Profiler.php
    │   │   Signal.php
    │   │   String.php
    │   │   Uri.php
    │   │
    │   ├───Profiler
    │   │       Exception.php
    │   │       Timer.php
    │   │
    │   └───Signal
    │           Exception.php
    │           Handler.php
    │           Interface.php
    │
    ├───Node
    │       Abstract.php
    │       Channel.php
    │       Channelgroup.php
    │       Client.php
    │       Exception.php
    │       Host.php
    │       Server.php
    │       Servergroup.php
    │
    ├───Transport
    │       Abstract.php
    │       Exception.php
    │       TCP.php
    │       UDP.php
    │
    └───Viewer
            Html.php
            Interface.php
            Text.php
```

My Controller constructor:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'teamspeak/teamspeak3'));
    $this->load->helper(array('url'));

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters($this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth'));
}
```

I try to load the function like this:

```
$ts3_VirtualServer = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://myquerry user:mysecretpassword@mysearveraddress:10011/?server_port=9987");
$ts3_VirtualServer->clientGetByName("My_User")->kick(TeamSpeak3::KICK_SERVER, "My kick message");
```

Comment: \application\libraries\ teamspeak\TeamSpeak3.php maybe this is just a typo - but is there a space before the name teamspeak?

Comment: Yes it is just a typo.

Comment: It seems the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496587/class-teamspeak3-helper-uri-not-found

Comment: Okay. Tested it and it seems to work! Thank you very much!